# How can one counter-argue this argument against the existence of God?

Tags: nature-of-god, apologetics, existence-of-god, perfection

Argument:

> If God is the Creator, He cannot be perfect. For either God created the world desiring it or not desiring it. If he did not wish it, it implies that he does not have total control over his actions, therefore he is not perfect. If he wanted to, either the creation suited him in the long run or not. If it didn't suit him, then he lacked something that suited him, then he wasn't perfect. If it didn't suit him, he has acted against his ultimate interests, so he is irrational, and therefore not perfect.

How can I counterargument this?

Comment: What is "suited him" supposed to mean?

Comment: Is this in reference to Genesis? It's well discussed that Genesis doesn't seem to depict a perfect God. He makes a creation that falls, he kills everything and regrets it, etc. If this argument was inspired by Genesis, then replying to it in isolation doesn't help.

Comment: @fгedsbend It would _not_ be a perfect creation that had _no choice_, but was _forced_ to abide by God's will and remain "perfect."  The very fact that Mankind had the option of falling, and was not forced, but actually _did_ fall is actually the greater evidence for God's perfection and love.

Comment: @Biblasia You make my point, that if this quote references Genesis, then the volumes about the fall bringing more perfection are part of an answer. Otherwise, what's the question about?

Comment: This at best argues that God is imperfect; it certainly does not argue that God does not exist as suggested in the title. You'd also need the premise that "If God exists, God is perfect" to conclude that.

Comment: @T.E.D. That's not what you first said. You called it impotent word games and that they should be ignored. And no one asked for nor implied they asked for complete logical refuge. Indeed, faith precludes it.

Comment: "If it didn't suit him, then he lacked something that suited him" I take it you mean "If it did suit him"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The original argument says:

> If God is the Creator, He cannot be perfect. For either God created the world desiring it or not desiring it. If he did not wish it, it implies that he does not have total control over his actions, therefore he is not perfect. If he wanted to, either the creation suited him in the long run or not. If it suited him, then he lacked something that suited him, then he wasn't perfect. If it didn't suit him, he has acted against his ultimate interests, so he is irrational, and therefore not perfect.

Let's parse this argument into formal logic:

**Premises**

- P1: *God created the world*
- P2: *God created the world* => *God desired to create the world* OR *God did not desire to create the world*
- P3: *God did not desire to create the world* => *God does not have self-control*
- P4: *God does not have self-control* => *God is NOT perfect*
- P5: *God desired to create the world* => *Creation suited God in the long run* OR *Creation did not suit God in the long run*
- P6: *Creation suited God in the long run* => *God lacked something that suited Him in the long run*
- P7: *God lacked something that suited Him in the long run* => *God is NOT perfect*
- P8: *Creation did not suit God in the long run* => *God is irrational*
- P9: *God is irrational* => *God is NOT perfect*

**Deductions**

- D1: *God desired to create the world* OR *God did not desire to create the world* (from P1 & P2)
- D2: *God did not desire to create the world* => *God is NOT perfect* (from P3 & P4)
- D3:  *Creation suited God in the long run* => *God is NOT perfect* (from P6
  & P7)
- D4:  *Creation did not suit God in the long run* => *God is NOT perfect* (from P8 & P9)
- D5: *God desired to create the world* => *God is NOT perfect* (from P5, D3 & D4)
- D6: *God is NOT perfect* (from D1, D2 & D5)

The argument is logically valid. The question is whether it is *sound*. To attack the soundness of this argument, one needs to call into question its premises. In particular, I find Premises 6 and 7 questionable. Why should we accept that, if something suits God, then God must lack something, and therefore God must be imperfect? Why can't something suit God even if God doesn't lack anything? These premises seem arbitrary, and they are based on implicit assumptions about the meaning of the concepts *something suiting God*, *perfection of God* and *God lacking something*. Notice there is also an implicit assumption about **God's relationship to time** (a [philosophically controversial topic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/eternity/)), as the argument talks about the creation suiting God *in the long run*. What exactly is meant by all these concepts, and why should we accept these definitions?

In sum, you can reject this argument by expressing your skepticism toward its questionable or unsubstantiated premises, until the arguer offers compelling reasons to accept them (or fails to do so).

Comment: Good breakdown. This is essentially the ancient/classical argument against the fact of creation (it says nothing about God) by citing the inability for what is perfect to change. Resurfaced during the re-exploration of the Greeks by the civilized Arab world in 11th-13th centuries...

Comment: Just a related comment on premises 6 and 7: "in the long run" implies the existence of time. In my experience, when the existence of time itself becomes part of a discussion, our ability to logically reason about whatever topic is at hand becomes wholly inadequate. Considering God's nature outside the confines of creation/time is a very high thought, as high even as the heavens are than the earth.

Comment: Nice use of formal logic, +1

Answer (score 11):

Mark had a good answer, to which I will add a separate angle.

The word "perfect" can mean essentially two things in English:

1. Flawless/pure; and
2. Complete/finished.

It appears to me that the question conflates these, claiming or implying that because God's creation was not completely finished (#2), God is not without flaw (#1).  But these are two different things, and the question itself is what is flawed.

Consider:
A "perfect" child Jesus was not yet "complete" according to Luke 2:52, for he continued to grow, learn, and develop.

> And Jesus increased in wisdom and stature, and in favour with God and
> man. (Luke 2:52, KJV; cf. vs. 40)

Development (increasing) does not imply imperfection.

Answer (score 10):

Even as a heathen atheist and cultural Jew I can see the problem with this. Any argument based on "God is perfect" presumes that we're able to judge what perfection is. The argument you quoted is based on an arbitrary definition of perfection deliberately chosen so that it would not be consistent with some actions that God purportedly took.

I believe logicians would call this a strawman argument.

Comment: The irony of man defining what is his Creator's idea of perfection.

Comment: Also known as hubris.

Comment: C.S. Lewis called this 'putting God in the dock'.

Answer (score 5):

I would ask him first, "How do you know that God is not perfect? What he is doing is making "an argument from silence." One cannot make a positive assertion of truth based on what is NOT said.

In short, his argument is "fallacious." There are a number of verses that claim God is perfect. Psalms 18:30, Deuteronomy 32:4 and one more, 2 Samuel 22:31.

Even Jesus Christ is identified as perfect and sinless according to 1 Peter 2:22,  and at John 1:14, "And the Word became flesh, and dwelt among us, and we beheld His glory, glory as of the only begotten from the Father, FULL OF GRACE AND TRUTH." Ask him to reconcile his opinion with the Scriptures.

Comment: I think it should be clear that someone who finds fault with God will find fault with the Bible, and would not be inclined to accept the scriptures as authoritative--hence there would be little point in asking him or her "to reconcile his opinion with the Scriptures."

Comment: Look Biblasia, why are you straining at "gnats?" The poster ask how he can counter the question he was ask. All I did was tell him what I would do and your objecting? I didn't know you had the ability to know the operation of one's mind. Now, you brought up Jesus as a boy who was not yet complete so answer me this question? As a boy was Jesus perfect and sinless even from His mother's womb?

Comment: "For he hath made him to be sin for us, **who knew no sin;** that we might be made the righteousness of God in him." (2 Corinthians 5:21, KJV)

Comment: @Biblasia So what is your point of quoting this verse? I'm asking your what the verse means to you? It means to me that Jesus Christ is sinless because it explicitly states, "who knew no sin." Or to put this another way, God treats the sinless Christ as though He were a sinner in a legal sense. Romans 8:3-4 "For what the law could not do, weak as it was through the flesh, God did; sending His own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh and as an offering for sin. He condemned sin in the flesh." Vs4, in order that the requirement of the Law might be fulfilled in us etc."

Comment: The verse is clear that Jesus never sinned.  If he "knew no sin," he cannot have sinned at any point in time during his life, including his childhood.

Comment: @Biblasia Your absolutely right. Since this is true and the Bible clearly teaches that "ALL" men are sinners, without exception at Romans 3:23-24, Romans 5:12, "Therefore, just as sin came into the world through one man, and death through sin, and so death spread to ALL men because ALL sinned." Romans 3:10, "As it is written; "None is righteous, NO, NOT ONE." Here's one in the OT, Jeremiah 17:9-10, "The heart is deceitful above all things, And desperately wicked; Who can no it?" There was no deceit in Jesus so explain how this man who you claim is not God was able to be perfect and sinless?

Comment: @MrBond With that twisted logic you will soon have all believing that Jesus was either NOT a man, or he was a liar, because: "God forbid: yea, let God be true, but every man a liar; as it is written, That thou mightest be justified in thy sayings, and mightest overcome when thou art judged." (Romans 3:4). You are so set on proving that which the Bible does not teach that you are willing to nullify the entire plan of redemption, as one devoid of spiritual understanding. Spiritual things are spiritually discerned. If you seriously doubt Jesus' character, you need to ask God about it--not me.

Comment: @Biblasia What are you talking about? Of course Jesus was a man. Why do you think He often referred to Himself as "the Son of Man" and (btw) "the Son of God?" He's the Son of God on His Father's side which is deity. He's the Son of Man on His mother's side which is human. He has two natures and you can prove wrong by giving me an example of a son that does not share the same nature as its father. Also, Philippians 2:5-8 explains this in clear terms. Jesus told Nicodemus at John 3:12, "I have spoken to you of earthy things and you do not believe, how then will you believe heavenly things?"

Comment: @MrBond Jesus most frequently referred to himself as "the son of man."  With this in mind, it appears you do not believe the whole Bible, as you cannot accept a plain "thus saith the LORD" as presented in Numbers 23:19 and in 1 Samuel 15:29.  Here's the part that you cannot believe: "God is not a man, that he should lie; neither the son of man, that he should repent:" (Num. 23:19).  You have said "Of course Jesus was a man."  Do you really believe that?

Comment: @Biblasia What your doing is taking Numbers 23:19 out of context, or should I say misinterpreting it. Of course this is a common mistake when folks use this verse to prove God is not a man. Look at it closely. God is not a man, that He should lie. In other words, "God is not like men who lie, nor a son of man, that He should repent. It's talking about Gods "character" which is NOT like a man's character who lies. Nor when God speaks, He will keep His word. Your turn, next excuse?

Comment: @MrBond If you prefer to maintain your present belief and the explanation you just gave, you had better never learn Hebrew so as to read Numbers 23:19 in the original.  If you do, you will find that your opinion of it is untenable.  Hint: The word "like" is not there, nor even implied.  Hebrew grammar requires the verb of being here--the very same verb of being that is required in the translation of Deuteronomy 6:4.  You wouldn't say "Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God is _like_ one LORD," would you? Actually, maybe you would--being that you believe God is three, not one as the Bible says He is.

Comment: @Biblasia This is my last post on this topic, unless of course you want to take this to chat? Please read the following which helps explain my point. Since you have a problem with the word "like" maybe I should have said, "unlike men" who etc. It's explained here: https://dailyverse.knowing-jesus.com/numbers-23-19

Comment: It's quite simple: God is not _like_ a man because He _isn't_ a man--even as the Bible plainly reads.

Answer (score 3):

The argument never addresses the possibility God intentionally created a world that suits him. It leaves this option completely open. It just so happens this is the result Christians claim. Furthermore, the omission is meant to be *obvious*. Clearly we live in a flawed and broken world, and how could a perfect and powerful God allow that? This actually attacks the Christian worldview as so absurd as to not even be worth mentioning or considering.

A more modern way to view this restates it like this, to state the issue explicitly:

> If God is good, he is not God. And if he is God, he is not good.

The existence of cancer in children is also often brought up as a common case-in-point. A child has not sinned. How could a perfect God allow such a thing to happen to a sinless person? He must be either powerless to stop it or a participant in making it happen. Ultimately, this is the problem of how we deal with suffering.

My answer has to come in two parts: one to address the specific and one to address the abstract.

I'll start with the specific. While I can go several directions making abstract arguments for the general problem, that's not helpful in the moment. For the person dealing with suffering *right now*, I don't want do anything other than be present with them and offer comfort. It's important to make that plain first. When suffering happens, all the other lofty logic we might produce is counter-productive and calloused.

Having stated this, the context we have right now is more of an abstract question, inviting us to respond on that axis at length. Still, I prefer brevity and I'll reframe the problem one final time in order to keep this short. We can reduce it down to this:

> Why didn't God create a perfect world?

It is fundamentally the same issue as first posed, and we can answer like this: "He did. Twice." The world as it was first created was perfect. It was only after mankind brought sin into the world that we had any death or suffering. A child has cancer not because of their sin, but because they were born into a corrupted and sinful world. One could argue this itself is a flaw, but the Christian can respond even this was also part of God's plan from the beginning, that the world will be *redeemed* and anyone who wishes can be with God in Heaven, where there will be no sin, no suffering, and the joy there is so far greater than any previous suffering as to render it meaningless.

Comment: "The argument never addresses the possibility God intentionally created a world that suits him." I think it's pretty clear that in "If it didn't suit him, then he lacked something that suited him", the "didn't" is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like the reasoning of Leibniz. In short, his argumentation goes like this: God is omnipotent, so He can do whatever is possible. He is also good, so He created the world as good as possible. So, whatever we may not like about the world, whatever we would call “less than perfect” about the world, still is the best possible world.

The argument is not undisputed. It has been ridiculed by other philosophers and for a Christian it may be a bit problematic to accept the idea that even God can not do the impossible. But it is an interesting philosophical idea, I think, that resembles things you can find in Holy Scripture. For example, when Job calls God to answer for all the wrongs God has done to Job. God doesn’t explain himself to Job, He doesn’t stand trial. On the contrary, He questions Jobs right to call God to answer for Himself.

In a way, that is what Leibniz says in a more modern philosophical way: *we* can think something is evil or wrong in the world, and that is Gods fault, but who are we to question God? If this is the world created by God, we *must* assume and accept that this is the world as it should be, the best possible world.

(see also: https://www.britannica.com/topic/best-of-all-possible-worlds )

Answer (score 1):

The argument cited in the Question looks like an elaborated version of the age- old riddle: " Can God create a stone so big that he himself cannot lift ? " . In fact Genesis only says that God saw the things created by him as 'Good' , and not as 'Perfect.' If the universe , with all the living beings in it, has survived so far, it is because it has incessantly been rejuvenating itself through the process of living and dying. One cannot just wish away death if one wants the universe to be rejuvenated. Agreed that it is sinful for human beings to kill one another. But, animals have formed a cycle of consuming one another for food, as a part of their programming. So, if God allowed his creation to die in order to pave way for newer generations , and let His Only Son die for ensuring eternal life of humankind, it should only be seen as an outcome of His Infinite Wisdom, something incomprehensible by human standards !